# warning C4995 vs error C4995

Tags: visual-c++, oculus

When I build a project (with VS2012) I get folowing output several times:

```
 warning C4995: 'DwmEnableComposition': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
```

When I copy the projects sourcefiles into another project (and different solution) I get errors instead of warnings (and the build does not succeed):

```
error C4995: 'DwmEnableComposition': name was marked as #pragma deprecated
```

Is there anything I can do that I get warnings instead of errors?

That is the project I am running (it's not my own code): http://federico-mammano.github.io/Oculus-SDK-0.4.4-beta-OpenGL-Demo/ (the OpenGL example)

Comment: The warnings tell you something is wrong. Trying to use a program that the compiler warned you about will result in undefined behavior

Comment: Yes but if the code works in one project it should also work in antoher project, shouldn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily, there is also compiler options/ flags that suppress warnings, and will compile; maybe even partly work; but it will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You probably have 'SDL checks' enabled for the project where you get an error (under C/C++ -> General). It's an option in the 'new project' wizard. Remove that and it'll revert back to a warning.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `DwmEnableComposition` function. Is deprecated as of Windows 8.

When the compiler encounters a deprecated symbol like in this case, it issues C4995.

More info:

[DwmEnableComposition function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa969510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[Compiler Warning (level 3) C4995](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8wsycdzs.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I just confirmed this behavior in an existing project, in which I decided today to enable SDL checks in the unit test program for one of my C++ libraries. The function that flagged is one of my own that I marked as deprecated, but it has nothing to do with security, per se. So, I say that this begs the question; why is the compiler treating it as an error, when every other time I've used SDL checks that flagged such uses as *swprintf*, **C4995** is a **warning**?